How to config SSH authentication with all 3 components: publickey, password and OTP
Update 1: I'm able to apply all publickey + password + OTP with this basic config in /etc/pam.d/common-auth.
auth [success=ok] pam_unix.so
auth [success=1] pam_google_authenticator.so nullok echo_verification_code  [authtok_prompt=Enter your OTP:]
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    required                        pam_permit.so

I will try to apply pam_faillock.so to this as the original plan.

Original question:
I'm using Debian 10 and 12 and would like to make my users only successfully SSH to the server if they have matched publickey, then input their password, and then follow with OTP (google-authenticator). In short, SSH should require publickey + password + OTP.
I already successfully config the combination of publickey + password or publickey + OTP, but still struggle to combine all of the three.
Please help me configure it.
My try so far:
/etc/pam.d/common-auth
auth    required       pam_faillock.so preauth audit silent deny=5 unlock_time=1800
auth    sufficient     pam_unix.so try_first_pass
auth    [default=die]  pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=5 fail_interval=120 unlock_time=1800
auth    sufficient     pam_faillock.so authsucc audit deny=5 fail_interval=120 unlock_time=1800
auth    required [success=1] pam_google_authenticator.so echo_verification_code
auth    requisite      pam_deny.so
auth    required       pam_permit.so

/etc/pam.d/sshd
@include common-auth
account    required     pam_nologin.so
@include common-account
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
@include common-session
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate
session    optional     pam_mail.so standard noenv # [1]
session    required     pam_limits.so
session    required     pam_env.so # [1]
session    required     pam_env.so user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so open
@include common-password

/etc/ssh/sshd_config
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
MaxAuthTries 5
MaxSessions 1
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords no
KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
ClientAliveInterval 60
ClientAliveCountMax 15
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
AuthenticationMethods publickey,password,keyboard-interactive

When trying to connect: ssh -i <key_path> user@server -vvv
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: <key_path>
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: 
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
Authenticated with partial success.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
debug3: start over, passed a different list password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@server's password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
Authenticated with partial success.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: entering
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
(user@server) Password:
debug3: send packet: type 61
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: entering
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
(user@server) Password:
debug3: send packet: type 61
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: entering
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
(user@server) Password:
debug3: send packet: type 61
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
user@server: Permission denied (keyboard-interactive).


It failed in step 3 (keyboard-interactive), and some things were different from the normal OTP verification:

It did not ask for the Verification code: but just asked (user@server) Password:.
It did not show the raw OTP code when I inputted despite config echo_verification_code in common-auth.

P/s: I also configured pam_faillock.so to lockout users for failed login attempts.

Welcome to the site. It seems you have made some progress in finding the solution yourself. In that case, please don't post updates in your question, but write your own answer to this question once you have found a viable solution.

Thank you. I will post the answer if I find the full solution (combine pam_faillock.so into my config). Right now, it is just some step forward so I updated it to anyone have a new overview about my problem.

After some tries, and thanks to this post, I'm able to add pam_faillock.so to my solution for checking logging attempts and locking the user if needed.

Be careful when editing those authentication-related files below. Always make a backup of the file first. And remember to keep one root session alive, and test your login in the other session.

Let's see my config files:
First: Edit /etc/pam.d/common-auth to apply to all kinds of login methods:
auth    requisite       pam_faillock.so preauth audit deny=5 fail_interval=120 unlock_time=1800
auth    [success=1]     pam_unix.so try_first_pass
auth    [default=die]   pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=5 fail_interval=120 unlock_time=1800
auth    [success=2]     pam_google_authenticator.so nullok echo_verification_code  [authtok_prompt=Enter your OTP:]
auth    sufficient      pam_faillock.so authsucc audit deny=5 fail_interval=120 unlock_time=1800
auth    requisite       pam_deny.so
auth    required        pam_permit.so

Some explanation line by line:

Use pam_faillock.so with preauth and requisite will check the status of the user. If the user is locked then prevent the password prompt. Followed by some config of faillock that you can check in here.
Use pam_unix.so to check the password of the user. [success=1] will skip the next line if the password is correct. try_first_pass to use the input of the first step.
pam_faillock.so with authfail will log the failed attempt, and prevent the authen process go further with [default=die]. If you want the user don't know where is failing (password or OTP) then swap lines 3 and 4.
Use pam_google_authenticator.so to check the OTP. You can find more info here. [success=2] will skip the next two lines if the OTP is correct.
pam_faillock.so with authsucc mark this attempt is good and will clear the bad attempt records, allowing the user to go further.
pam_deny.so with requisite will deny the login attempt. So some lines above skip this line if the info is correct.
pam_permit.so simply permit access after all the checking above.

Second: Edit /etc/pam.d/common-account and add this line in the beginning to use faillock:
account required        pam_faillock.so

Third: Edit /etc/pam.d/sshd for SSH connection. I changed nothing from the default config, just listed it here for you guys to compare.
@include common-auth
account    required     pam_nologin.so
@include common-account
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
@include common-session
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate
session    optional     pam_mail.so standard noenv # [1]
session    required     pam_limits.so
session    required     pam_env.so # [1]
session    required     pam_env.so user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so open
@include common-password

Fourth: Edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config to config the SSH session
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
MaxAuthTries 5
MaxSessions 1
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords no
KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
ClientAliveInterval 60
ClientAliveCountMax 15
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive

Some key items:

KbdInteractiveAuthentication = yes to using keyboard-interactive method. ChallengeResponseAuthentication is a deprecated alias for this.
UsePAM must be set to yes to use all the PAM configs above
In AuthenticationMethods, I only declare keyboard-interactive for both password and OTP prompt.

After editing the sshd_config file, reload the sshd service to update the new config.
systemctl reload sshd

And like this, I can check for all public key + password (of the user) + OTP.
